# Redirect AWS SES Emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I run an AWS Elastic-Beanstalk environment and have set up AWS SES. I have a `support@my-domain.com` email address which sends and receives emails. So far so good. However the emails sent to `support@my-domain.com` are stored in my S3 bucket as individual files. Because it is an email address for general support, messages directed towards it will be answered by a support team (which cannot be asked to download individual files from S3). My thought was to redirect emails addressed to `support@my-domain.com` to some other email address. Can I do that via AWS SES or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution: create AWS WorkMail account for `support@my-domain.com` address. In this case you can work with this address though web-interface or email application, you can set different rules for incoming messages.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should have a DL or inbox for support team. If not possible then use S3 events to trigger lambda and it will send attachment.
We can receive emails using SES, You can read more about it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html .
In case you want notifs for email bounce you can setup ConfigurationSet to get delivery/failed/bounce: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-configuration-sets.html
We are using both of these ways to send promotional emails. There is a link in our mails to unsubscribe. And if customer blocks our email or email id is incorrect we get a mail. For application failure stacktrace we send mails to support inbox and all developers can access it from their outlook.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it using sns topic and lambda function.in which your email come to SES and check for forward

here sharing one link you can refer it : https://medium.com/@ashan.fernando/forwarding-emails-to-your-inbox-using-amazon-ses-2d261d60e417

You can read documentation and click on Launch stack button it will mnake direct cloud formation for you in your aws account and deploy everything.

You can also follow this link : https://github.com/arithmetric/aws-lambda-ses-forwarder

in both cases lambda function will be used.

Comment: I have come across that already, thank you. But isn't there a simpler solution - maybe native to SES?

Comment: i donot think there is native solution. ses rules also no option for forward.

Comment: but you can make lambda function on new s3 iteam it has to forward it to particular email simple it will be